# ReactJS / React Bootstrap / Button / Link

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple login page in React using 'react-bootstrap'. This is a simple login screen with "Login" and "Register" buttons, with user being re-directed to a "Register" page on click on "Register" button. Below is my code lines...

```
 <td><Button variant="primary" id="login" type="submit" margin="10px">Login</Button>
 {" "}
 <Button variant="link" id="register" type="Button" margin="10px" href="/registrationForm">Register</Button>
 </td>
```

I have tried to check official documentation of 'react-bootstrap', but didn't find any example showing how to use button variant "link" for transferring code execution to a different page.

How to transfer execution to a different page by clicking on button with variant set as "link"?

P.S.: I have already tried to search online as well as on SE, but couldn't find a real working example.

Thanks,

Abhay Desai

Comment: Which language is this exactly? If you want more people to reach to this question, please retag it to its corresponding language.

Comment: variant="link" in react bootstrap is the style of the button not a link that will route you to another component. If you want to be redirected to another component use a router or do something onClick

Comment: Agreed, I am already using a Router on my home page to redirect User to different pages depending on user selection, but current scenario doesn't need a router.


This is a simple login page with 2 buttons, one as "Login" and another one as "Register" for Users who are not registered yet and want to register and get access to this application.


So, how to create this simple form with 2 buttons where User can be re-directed to "Register" screen on click of "Register" button?